# jQuery target iframe with link

Tags: jquery, html, iframe

I generate links to select galeriecategories to show in the frontend. It works all fine, but i just can't figure out how to submit this link to the iframe with the id submitter and name submitter...with jquery it returns my galerie

I generate my links like that...the first one is always #toggleRefCat0

```
echo "<a href=\"show.php?action=showGalerie&gaid=0&type=$type&view=$view\" target=\"submitter\" class=\"toggleRefCat\" id=\"toggleRefCat0\" >All</a>";
```

So I tried this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //$('#toggleRefCat0').click();
    //$('#toggleRefCat0').toggle();

    var thisCVAR = $('#toggleRefCat0').attr('href');
    $('#submitter').load(thisCVAR);
});
```

With a REAL click on that link it loads all perfectly...but with jquery click, toggle and the .load it doesn´t work...

The only solution (which comes to my mind) that would work 100% would be:
generating a form and submit this with jquery...but that´s way to complex...i think there must be a simpler solution....

Comment: Remove the `target` from your hyperlink (which will become useless here), and do that: `$('#submitter').attr('src', thisCVAR);`

Comment: Why didn´t you post an answer? :) ...works like it should...damn I feel stupid :/ thank you!

Comment: There you have an answer then.

Comment: just to accept it ;) more rep for you.

Comment: I'm glad to help, that's all. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the `target` from your hyperlink, which will become useless, and then set the `iframe` `src` value with `jQuery`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#toggleRefCat0')on('click', function(e) {
        // Stop the link default behaviour.
        e.preventDefault();

        // Set the iframe src with the clicked link href.
        $('#submitter').attr('src', $(this).attr('href'));
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much! accept in 8 minutes! I just don´t get why I forgot that...I knew that i could do that, but my brain wasn´t able to tell me :)